# Django Website for Oracle Backend

Tags: django, crud

Can anyone suggest me a tutorial on building a django website for a existing oracle database(tables included). Most of the tutorials I see are basically build from scratch tutorials , where DB is created with the application. WHat is Database is already present (with tables and data ofcourse) and I want to develop a crud application over it. Is there any sort of tutorial for that ?

Any inputs welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to look at "inspect-db command in the Django admin and work it out from there see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/